la pagina web no se renderiza en el navegador
estoy haciendo un proyecto de practica con html, css y bootstrap pero a la hora de visitar la pagina web encuentro que las imagenes no se cargan, dice que la ubicación no se encuentra y busqué y busqué el error y no lo consigo, no digo que me hagan la tarea.
solo si pueden orientarme por el camino que es y yo haré el restointroducir la descripción del vínculo aquí

Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Cuando te hagan observaciones, en lugar de mencionar que lo corregirás "la siguiente vez", procura [edit] tu pregunta para agregar más detalles.

Debes de eliminar el / al comienzo de la ruta de la imagen, esto src="/img/SHACK BURGUERS.png" cambialo por src="img/SHACK BURGUERS.png" y ya deberia de aparecer las imagenes.

Luis, no puedes responder a una pregunta que esté mal formulada, eso acostumbra a los usuarios hacer malas preguntas. Aunque tu sepas y tengas la respuesta debes pedirle el Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable que se plantea en [ask] y en el [tour]. Los mismo le dije a Stina y ni siquiera leíste eso

gracias luis, me ayudó. disculpen si formulé mal la pregunta, soy nueva y crei haberlo hecho bien. la siguiente vez revisaré con cuidado los detalles a la hora de formular preguntas feliz dia

Verifica que las rutas de las imágenes sean relativas al archivo HTML y que las imágenes estén en la carpeta correcta. Asegúrate de usar "/" o "./" correctamente.
<img src="./images/ejemplo.jpg" alt="Imagen de ejemplo">

Asegúrate de que la carpeta images esté en el mismo directorio que tu archivo HTML.
Mira que el ejemplo que muestras, dice: src="/img/SHACK BURGUERS.png" y cuando comienzas con / esa es la raíz del systema de ficheros local, y solo funciona en esa maquina y en ningún otro lugar del mundo.

No te olvides hacer click y cerrar la pregunta como respondida, asi mantenemos el sitio limpio y encontramos preguntas sin respuestas facilemente.

Stina, no puedes responder a una pregunta que esté mal formulada, eso acostumbra a los usuarios hacer malas preguntas. Aunque tu sepas y tengas la respuesta debes pedirle el Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable que se plantea en [ask] y en el [tour]

gracias sitina, me ayudó. disculpen si formulé mal la pregunta, soy nueva y crei haberlo hecho bien. la siguiente vez revisaré con cuidado los detalles a la hora de formular preguntas feliz dia

Cuando una respuesta es aceptada, no se cierra la pregunta. Las preguntas se cierran cuando, por ejemplo, necesitan más detalles para comprender el problema, tal como se dio en este caso. Si la pregunta es corregida, es posible reabrirla sin problemas.

Gracias por señalarlo. Entiendo la importancia de pedir más aclaraciones antes de responder, especialmente para ayudar a quien pregunta a mejorar la calidad de sus preguntas. En este caso, el problema me pareció claro y quise ofrecer una solución rápida. No estoy segura de por qué la pregunta fue cerrada, pero estaré más atenta a solicitar más detalles en el futuro si es necesario.
